# Why this network name is "AskDifferent" instead of Apple or any name related to Apple?

Tags: discussion

This SE network is all about Apple products.

But name is "Ask Different".

Why is that? I mean just looking at "Ask Different" we can't get any idea about site. But we can get a idea about what is about this site just looking at the name of most SE Network.